# fail to log through rsyslog on an archlinux system

Tags: arch-linux, syslog, rsyslog, logger

Using release 2016.03.01 from Archlinux, with package rsyslogd 8.18.0, I started from the minimal configuration built from [Very simple config](http://wiki.rsyslog.com/index.php/Very_simple_config_--_starting_point_for_modifications)
:

```
# cat rsyslog.conf
$ModLoad immark
$ModLoad imudp
$ModLoad imtcp
$ModLoad imuxsock
$ModLoad imklog

$template SyslFormat,"%timegenerated% [WJCG]-%HOSTNAME% %syslogtag%%msg:::space$

kern.debug /var/adm/syslog.dated/kern.log;SyslFormat
user.debug /var/adm/syslog.dated/user.log;SyslFormat
daemon.debug /var/adm/syslog.dated/daemon.log;SyslFormat
auth.crit;syslog.debug /var/adm/syslog.dated/syslog.log;SyslFormat
mail,lpr.debug /var/adm/syslog/misc.log;SyslFormat
kern.debug /var/adm/messages;SyslFormat
kern.debug /dev/console;SyslFormat
*.emerg *

local4.* /var/log/local4.log
```

Now, if I try (as a user or as root):

```
# echo hello|logger -p local4.info
```

Nothing is logged, no file `/var/log/local4.log` is created.
However at the end of the systemd journal, I've got:

```
# journalctl -xe|tail
Jun 10 18:32:17 mothership mobr[1681]: hello
Jun 10 18:38:09 mothership root[1696]: hello
```

Seems like systemd is messing with the regular log, but I cannot find how.
Any clue?

**Solved:**
by creating the log file: `# touch /var/log/local4.log`
and activating option `ForwardToSyslog=yes` in `/etc/systemd/journald.conf`

Comment: it used to be that syslog wanted the file to be present before it would write to it; try touching the local4.log first and re-test?

Comment: yes! that was it. Many thanks Jeff, feel free to write an answer.

Comment: wait, actually it solved the problem only for 1 of my 3 archlinux systems (all 3 have the exact same rsyslog configuration). There is possibly some systemd configuration to be done too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would welcome links for supporting documentation on this, as I cannot find it on rsyslog.com's site. It is apparent from OP's testing, though, that rsyslog (with the given configuration) will refuse to create new files; to enable logging to those files, create them first (e.g. `touch /var/log/local4.log`).

This has cropped up before in: [How to tell rsyslog to create log file if not there?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92522/how-to-tell-rsyslog-to-create-log-file-if-not-there) as that question asks about file deletion; file rotation via logrotate would be a similar case.

Comment: there is this special section of the archlinux wiki about rsyslog: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/rsyslog.

Comment: and this one about the interaction of systemd journal and rsyslog: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Journald_in_conjunction_with_syslog.